# Prove properties regarding the interior and frontier/boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology

I know there properties:

[image]

where A $\subseteq R^m$ is a set, A' is the set of all limit points of A, called the derived set of A.

But now I'm wondering how can they be proven?

Comment: Write down the definitions and try:)

Comment: I'm trying to do that right now. I'm at the first one. I said that x $\in$ A' and I assumed that x $\notin$ A because I'm trying to prove that if x $\notin$ A, then x $\in$ frA. @Bargabbiati

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\fr}{\operatorname{fr}}$
$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$

By the definition, $\fr A=\overline{A}\setminus\int A$. Therefore $A\cap \fr A=\overline{A}\supset A’$. Since $\int A\subset A$, $\int (\Bbb R^m\setminus A)\subset  \Bbb R^m\setminus A$, and $A\cap (\Bbb R^m\setminus A)=\varnothing$, $\int A\cap \int (\Bbb R^m\setminus A)=\varnothing$ as well. It is easy to check that $\fr A=\overline{A}\setminus\int A=\overline{A}\cap \overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus A}=\fr(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$. Finally, $A\setminus\fr A= A\setminus  (\overline{A}\setminus\int A)=\int A$.